# ResourceDictionary and AvalonDock

Tags: wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary, avalondock

This may be very simple but still I could't find any solutions.I have resource dictionary in my project which contain a datatemplate. When i load this in my project everything is visible except the part written using Avalondock.That place is always empty. But when I put the same code in a usercontrol everything is visible and fine.Is there something i should be aware when i add this to resourcedictionary?

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:vm1}">
    <Grid Background="Gray" Height="595" Width="775">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="115*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="256*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="222*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
       </Grid>
        <xca:DockingManager Grid.Row="1" > // from here is blank
            <xca:LayoutRoot>
                <xca:LayoutPanel>
                    <xca:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                        <xca:LayoutDocumentPane x:Name="layoutDocumentPane">
                            <xca:LayoutDocument Title="">
                                 <Grid>
                                    <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <Label Content="" />
                                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"/>
                                 </Grid>
                            </xca:LayoutDocument>
                            <xca:LayoutDocument Title=""/>
                            <xca:LayoutDocument Title=""/>
                        </xca:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    </xca:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                </xca:LayoutPanel>
            </xca:LayoutRoot>
        </xca:DockingManager> // till here
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,0,0,197" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <CheckBox Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,0,0,173" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,0,0,139" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Except the part written in the middle rest is visible

Comment: Can you try to force Height and Width for the DockManager itself?

Comment: Can you try to look on the visual tree by using a tool such as snoop?

Comment: @ArielBH i tried forcing the height and width no difference. as i mentioned in the usercontrol the same code shows that part